# Iframe content does not adjust to viewport

Tags: iframe, viewport

I'm trying to load an external site into an iframe. This external site adjusts perfectly to the viewport when loaded in a browser. However, when loaded in an iframe, the content does not adjust to fit the iframe's width.

Here is my HTML snippet:

```
<iframe height="500" width="100%" style="height:500px;width:100%" src="<external URL"></iframe>
```

Please note that I don't have control over the external site. But since that site already adjusts to the browser's width when loaded independently, then I'm thinking that I just need to be able to tell the content to use the iframe's width. Any suggestions on how achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot posting the code.

Comment: ah yes. forgot to mark it as code. thanks!